# How many bit strings of length 10 contain at least three 1s and at least three 0s?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Here is my solution.

```
1. assign 3 out of 10 bits for three 1s. -> C(10, 3)
2. assign 3 out of 7 bits for three 0s. -> C(7, 3)
3. assign left 4 bits for 0 or 1. -> 2^4

Since steps 1, 2, and 3 occur simultaneously, I multiplied the results of steps 1, 2, and 3 together.
```

I cannot spot the wrong spot. Please help me.

+Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: You are counting some combinations multiple times.  Say that there were exactly seven $1's$...how would you know which were the special three that you selected first and which were added later on?  This means that you count such combinations $\binom 73$ times.

Comment: To convince yourself, work a simpler problem:  how many binary strings of length $3$ have at least one $1$ and one $0$?  Your method gives $3$ ways to chose the special $1$, then $2$ ways to choose the special $0$, then $2$ ways to assign the other, so you get $3\times 2\times 2=12$ good combinations all in all.  But that's nonsense, as there are only $8$ binary strings of length $3$.

Comment: For a correct solution, consider counting all sequences regardless and remove from the count the "bad" sequences who had too few $0$'s or too few $1$'s.  Alternatively, sum over the possible good cases, three $1$'s and seven $0$'s, four $1$'s and six $0$'s, ..., seven $1$'s and three $0$'s.

Comment: Thank you so much! I could finish my discrete math assingment before the deadline because of your help:)